# sympyで三角関数の値を分数表示したい

Tags: python, sympy

(参考)wolframalphaなら、できました。
入力:
cos(x)=3/5,sin(x)
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28x%29%3D3%2F5%2Csin%28x%29&lang=ja
代入:
sin(x) = -4/5, sin(x) = 4/5

```
# 共通テスト2021 数学ⅠA問題　第1問〔2〕
# https://www.toshin.com/kyotsutest/data/285/sugaku-1a.pdf#page=7
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
ans=solve([cos(x)-3/5],x)
print(sin(ans[0][0]))

ans=solve([(3/5)**2+x**2-1],x)
print(ans[1][0])

print(sqrt(1-(3/5)**2))
# 出力
# 0.800000000000000
# 0.800000000000000
# 0.800000000000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rationalを使いましょう。

```
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x')
a = Rational(3,5)
ans=solve([cos(x)-a],x)
print(sin(ans[0][0]))

ans=solve([(a)**2+x**2-1],x)
print(ans[1][0])
#-4/5
#4/5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# 共通テスト2021 数学ⅠA問題　第1問〔2〕
# https://www.toshin.com/kyotsutest/data/285/sugaku-1a.pdf#page=7
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
a = Rational(3,5)
ans=solve([cos(x)-a],x)
print(sin(ans[1][0]))

ans=solve([a**2+x**2-1],x)
print(ans[1][0])

print(sqrt(1-a**2))
# 出力
# 4/5
# 4/5
# 4/5
```